# Is there an easy way to make shovebox sync on two Macs?

Tags: macos, sync

I have tried the Dropbox syncing method described in here:

http://milestinsley.com/2009/02/22/shove-your-box-in-to-dropbox/

And even though I tried to follow instruction very closely, I failed, probably because I suck unix commands.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't have enough information in it to be answerable, but I'm going to assume that's just because you're not sure where to start.

First thing's first--checking to see if ShoveBox's library is symlinked to its location in Dropbox.

In terminal, do `ls -l ~/Library/Application\ Support/Shovebox`

If the output shows a regular file and not a symlink, then you'll need to basically start over. If it is a symlink, the output will look something like `lrw-r--r--  1 user  group  198656 Jun 26 14:00 ShoveBox Database -> ../../../Dropbox/ShoveBox Database`

If not, it'll look more like `-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  198656 Jun 26 14:00 ShoveBox Database`

Give us some more information and we may be able to help.